# MSAccess via ODBC - squirrely behavior - DSN settings

Tags: ms-access, odbc, dsn

I am utilizing an MSAccess database on 2 machines in the same bldg. Machine1 has the database on it. Machine2 has a mapped drive to the database on Machine1. I can use the same key value on Machine1 and get a record, but using that same key value on machine2 I sometimes get no record found. But it IS there. Machine1 works flawlessly.

The correct fix would be to add SQLExpress and up-size the Access database, but I have reasons to avoid that for the time being.

I have changed the Timeout setting and the MaxScanRows settings in the DSN(ODBC)- MSAcess ODBC driver Advanced Setting- on Machine2 which seemed to fix the issue for today. I don't really know what those Advanced ODBC settings do and that's really my question here. Does anyone know what those settings do and which one might help me most?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried linking the table directly rather than through ODBC

Comment: No I haven't. I am trying not to change the code, as it is deployed successfully in 10-12 different locations and I am trying to keep it consistent among all the deployments. (I may have to try that if I can't fix this through ODBC tweaks)